# Vectors disappear

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

So I am having problem with my `Item::return_all()` as I call it in `main.cpp`. Earlier I tried `return_all` inside `read_file()` and `for (auto data : example_item)` loop printed data inside `item_` correctly. What is the reason `return_all()` doesn't return (or atleast main.cpp doesn't print it) data inside `item_`if I call it in main? Or does the data inside `item_` disappear due to some reason I don't know as my c++ knowledge is pretty limited.

Items.txt contains lines in format *"1001:0:6"*.

main.cpp

```
#include "item.hh"
#include "functions.hh"

int main() {
   Item item;
   read_file("items.txt");
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> example_item = item.return_all();
   for (auto data : example_item){
       for (auto data2 : data){
           std::cout << data2 << std::endl;
       }
   }
}
```

item.hh

```
class Item {

  public:
    Item();
    void add_item(std::vector<int> item);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> return_all();
    std::vector<int> return_item(const int& name) const;

  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> item_; 
};
```

item.cpp

```
#include "item.hh"
#include "functions.hh"

Item::Item(){}

void Item::add_item(std::vector<int> item){
    item_.push_back(item);
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> Item::return_all(){
    return item_;
}

std::vector<int> Item::return_item(const int& name) const {
    for (auto item : item_) {
        if (item.at(0) == name) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

functions.hh

```
void read_file(const std::string name);
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& string, char splitter);
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "item.hh"
#include "functions.hh"

void read_file(const std::string name){
       Item item;
       std::string line;
       std::ifstream myfile(name);
       if (myfile.is_open())
       {
         while (getline(myfile, line))
         {
             std::vector<std::string> field{};
             field = split(line, ':');
             int name = std::stoi(field.at(0));
             int type = std::stoi(field.at(1));
             int attr = std::stoi(field.at(2));
             std::vector<int> field_i = {name , type, attr};
             item.add_item(field_i);
         }
       }
         myfile.close();
   }

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& string, char splitter) {
    std::vector<std::string> fields{};
    std::string::size_type start_p{0};
    while ( true ) {
        std::string::size_type end_p{0};
        end_p = string.find(splitter, start_p);
        if ( end_p == std::string::npos ) {
            break;
        }
        std::string field{""};
        field = string.substr(start_p, end_p - start_p);
        fields.push_back(field);
        start_p = end_p + 1;
    }
    fields.push_back(string.substr(start_p));
    return fields;
}
```

Comment: where is `Item::return_all()` defined?

Comment: You're declaring `Item item;` within read_file which adds the data to its local then loses it when it returns. The `Item item;` in main is never touched.

Comment: I had accidentally deleted that as I edited the post. Now it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Item item;
read_file("items.txt");
```

to:

```
Item item = read_file("items.txt");
```

And the definition of `read_file` accordingly. As-is, that function is just reading the file into a local `Item` which is then destroyed. So your `item` is always empty because nothing every adds anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's one `Item` called "item" here:

```
int main() {
   Item item;
   read_file("items.txt");
```

and there's another one here:

```
void read_file(const std::string name){
   Item item;
```

These two are distinct objects, and you're only modifying the one in `read_file`.

The simplest way to fix this is to return an object from `read_file`:

```
Item read_file(const std::string name){
   Item item;
   // The rest of the code
   return item;
}

int main() {
   Item item = read_file("items.txt");
   // ...
```